# Algebraic structure vs Algebraic Object

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

What is the difference between algebraic structure and algebraic object? Are they same?

I googled it. But I didn't find anything useful.
Algebraic structure like groupoid. But what about algebraic object.

Comment: No meaningful difference that I can think of, though "algebraic object" isn't a term I see used very often; I suppose it could be used in a more general sense, such as for a specific permutation or something? Where have you seen the "algebraic object" term?

Comment: I think algebraic object means we care about what the object originally is. For example, $S_3$ and $D_6$ have the same algebraic structure, but are different objects.

Comment: A category has objects. So the category of groups has groups as objects and group homomorphisms as morphisms.